# Non-ES6 let Alternative

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a TinyMCE plugin for Wordpress and I've just run in to a little issue with how I'm approaching things. Basically, I'm using a loop which relies on a counter `i`. The loop is responsible for building an array with TinyMce details in it. One of those things is a function call which is passed the `i` counter.

But of course, by the time that the click actually registers, that counter is always at it's maximum. I solved this temporarily by using `let` in my loop. Here's the loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i <= pmsb.config.length - 1; i++) {
    menu[i] = {
        text: pmsb.config[i].title,
        onclick: function() {
            open_dialog(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that `let` isn't well supported and with this being a Wordpress plugin, I've no real control over the browsers which my target audience will use.

So in the case of the above loop - how do I make the function call receive the correct number (as `let` does)?

Comment: @EricLease: That will have the same issue. `for` loops don't have scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than a `for` loop, use `forEach` instead - the resulting callback will automatically receive the index as a parameter that will be correctly bound in scope:

```
pmsb.config.forEach(function(config, i) {
    menu[i] = {
        text: config.title,
        onclick: function() {
            open_dialog(i);
        }
    }
});
```

If (as appears likely) there's a one-to-one mapping from `pmsb.config[i]` to `menu[i]` you can better still use `.map` instead of `forEach`:

```
var menu = pmsb.config.map(function(config, i) {
    return {
        text: config.title,
        onclick: function() {
             open_dialog(i);
        }
    }
});
```